# symfony2 yaml: overwrite configuration

Tags: symfony, yaml

I cannot get the symfony2 configuration to correctly overwrite values from other config-files. Here is the problem:

I have a new environment "staging" where I want to use most of the stuff from config_prod.yml but have another logging level (I want it to be as it is in development, simply logging everything to a file). Here are the config stuff I use:

config_prod.yml:

```
imports:
    - { resource: config.yml }

monolog:
    handlers:
        main:
            type: fingers_crossed
            action_level: error
            handler: nested
        nested:
            type: stream
            path: %kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log
            level: debug
```

config_staging.yml:

```
imports:
    - { resource: config_prod.yml }

monolog:
    handlers:
        main:
            type: stream
            path: %kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log
            level: debug
        nested: ~
```

From my point of view, the nested logger is now null and the main logs to the given file. **What really happens is that he logs every message twice!** The same happens when I use this for the config_staging.yml:

```
imports:
    - { resource: config_prod.yml }

monolog:
    handlers:
        main:
            type: stream
            path: %kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log
            level: debug
            handler: ~
        nested: ~
```

I found a workaround, setting the action_level of the main handler to debug and leaving everything else as is, but I don't like this solution. There must be a way to overwrite config stuff so I only have the main monolog handler.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Pretty much one year later I now have an understanding of what's happening and how to prevent it:

The `nested` handler is befilled with the configuration from the `config.yml` and when parsing the `config_staging.yml`, the yaml component does not overwrite the whole hashmap and set the value to null but tries to merge both, resulting in the same array as before.

There is a type called `null` which can be used ot overwrite any Logger. It does nothing and is therefor suitable for this use case:

```
monolog:
    handlers:
        main:
            type: stream
            path: %kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log
            level: debug
            handler: ~
        nested: ~
            type: null
```

Another solution would be to not configure any logging in the config.yml but only in the specific environment configs like `config_prod.yml` and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Check that you don't have any repeated keys in the _staging config file -- the second one would override the first, with the net result that the first is ignored.

Comment: I checked this one, no dublicated keys in there!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to alter a collection by removing an element you will have to create an intermediate YAML file (importing the base) setting the collection to "null" and re-adding all required collection elements in a file which in turn imports the intermediate YAML file.

You can not simply overwrite a collection. New elements will get added but you can't remove existing ones except by the workaround described.